# Trouble trying to automatically save checklist items which clicked

Tags: plugin-options

I am trying to save the values of multiple checklists using update_option and individual options for each item. I am getting a 400 Error in the console when making POST requests to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. Please help if you can!

*index.php:*

```
function settings_html_content() {
    $details = get_option('details-checkbox');
    $socials = get_option('socials-checkbox');
    $topic_wheel = get_option('topic-wheel-checkbox');
    $testimonials = get_option('testimonials-checkbox');

    ?>
    
        <h2>Setup Checklist</h2>
        <form id="autosave-checklist-form" action="options.php">                                                                       
            <label for="details" id="details" name="details"><input type="checkbox" id="details" name="details" label="details" value="<?php echo esc_attr($details); ?>" <?php checked($details); ?>>Submit the <a href="?page=bm-plugin&tab=details">"Personal Branding Details" form</a>.</label>
            <label for="socials"  id="socials" name="socials"><input type="checkbox" id="socials" name="socials" label="socials" value="<?php echo esc_attr($socials); ?>" <?php checked($socials); ?>>Submit the <a href="?page=bm-plugin&tab=socials">"Social Media Accounts" form</a>.</label>
            <label for="topic-wheel" id="topic-wheel" name="topic-wheel"><input type="checkbox" id="topic-wheel" name="topic-wheel" label="topic-wheel" value="<?php echo esc_attr($topic_wheel); ?>" <?php checked($topic_wheel); ?>>Submit the <a href="?page=bm-plugin&tab=topic-wheel">"Topic Wheel" form</a>.</label>
            <label for="testimonials" id="testimonials" name="testimonials"><input type="checkbox" id="testimonials" name="testimonials" label="testimonials" value="<?php echo esc_attr($testimonials); ?>" <?php checked($testimonials); ?>>Submit the <a href="?page=bm-plugin&tab=testimonials">"Testimonials" form</a>.</label>
            <p>For more information please read our <a href="">documention</a>.</p>
            <?php
                settings_fields( 'checklist_settings_group' );
                do_settings_sections( 'bm_plugin' );
                submit_button();
            ?>
        </form>                                                        
    <?php
}

function autosave_checklist_handler() {                                 
    // $json_input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    // Get the checklist item value from the AJAX request                    
    $option = $_POST['option'];                                                  
    $item = $_POST['item'];
                                                                             
    // Update the checklist in the options table                             
    // update_option($option, $item); 
    update_option( $_POST['option'], $_POST['item'] );     
    ?>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li> 
                    Option: <?php echo $option ?>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    Item: <?php echo $item ?>
                </li>
            </ul>       
        </div> 
    <?php    
    
    // Return a success response                                             
    wp_send_json_success(array('details: ' => true));
}   
add_action('wp_ajax_autosave_checklist', 'autosave_checklist_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_autosave_checklist', 'autosave_checklist_handler');  

function register_bm_settings() { 
    register_setting( 'checklist_settings_group', 'details-checkbox' );
    register_setting( 'checklist_settings_group', 'socials-checkbox' );
    register_setting( 'checklist_settings_group', 'topic-wheel-checkbox' );
    register_setting( 'checklist_settings_group', 'testimonials-checkbox' );
}

function bm_css_and_js($hook) {

    wp_enqueue_style('bm_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'css/styles.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('autosave-checklist-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'autosave-checklist.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);                    
    wp_localize_script(
        'autosave-checklist-script', 
        'autosaveChecklist',     
        array(                                                                       
            'ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') 
        )
    );
}

function bm_add_admin_page() {

    add_menu_page(
        'BlitzMetrics', 
        'BlitzMetrics', 
        'manage_options', 
        'bm-plugin', 
        'bm_admin_page_html',
        plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/images/icon.png'
      );

}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'bm_css_and_js' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_bm_settings' );
```

*autosaving-checklist.js:*

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const details = document.querySelector('#details');
    const socials = document.querySelector('#socials');
    const topicWheel = document.querySelector('#topic-wheel');
    const testimonials = document.querySelector('#testimonials');

    details.addEventListener('change', () => {
        console.log('autosaveChecklist: ' + JSON.stringify(autosaveChecklist))
        console.log('details: ' + details.checked)
        fetch(autosaveChecklist.ajaxUrl + '?action=wp_ajax_autosave_checklist', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                action    : 'wp_ajax_autosave_checklist',
                option: 'details-checkbox',
                item: document.getElementById('details').checked
            },
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });

    socials.addEventListener('change', () => {
        console.log('autosaveChecklist: ' + JSON.stringify(autosaveChecklist))
        console.log('socials: ' + socials.checked)
        fetch(autosaveChecklist.ajaxUrl + '?action=wp_ajax_autosave_checklist', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                action    : 'wp_ajax_autosave_checklist',
                option: 'socials-checkbox',
                item: document.getElementById('socials').checked
            }),
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });

    topicWheel.addEventListener('change', () => {
        console.log('autosaveChecklist: ' + JSON.stringify(autosaveChecklist))
        console.log('topicWheel: ' + topicWheel.checked)
        fetch(autosaveChecklist.ajaxUrl + '?action=wp_ajax_autosave_checklist', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                action    : 'wp_ajax_autosave_checklist',
                option: 'topic-wheel-checkbox',
                item: document.getElementById('topic-wheel').checked
            }),
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });

    testimonials.addEventListener('change', () => {
        console.log('autosaveChecklist: ' + JSON.stringify(autosaveChecklist))
        console.log('testimonials: ' + testimonials.checked)
        fetch(autosaveChecklist.ajaxUrl + '?action=wp_ajax_autosave_checklist', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                action    : 'wp_ajax_autosave_checklist',
                option: 'testimonials-checkbox',
                item: document.getElementById('testimonials').checked
            }),
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencode with new URLSearchParams(body).toString() instead of JSON.stringify(body).

autosave-checklist.js

```
details.addEventListener('change', () => {
        fetch(autosaveChecklist.ajaxUrl + '?action=autosave_checklist', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                action    : 'autosave_checklist',
                option: 'details-checkbox',
                item: details.checked
            }).toString(),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));;
    });

    socials.addEventListener('change', () => {
        fetch(autosaveChecklist.ajaxUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                action    : 'autosave_checklist',
                option: 'socials-checkbox',
                item: socials.checked
            }).toString(),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });

    topicWheel.addEventListener('change', () => {
        // console.log('topicWheel: ' + topicWheel.checked)
        fetch(autosaveChecklist.ajaxUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                action    : 'autosave_checklist',
                option: 'topic-wheel-checkbox',
                item: topicWheel.checked
            }).toString(),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));;
    });

    testimonials.addEventListener('change', () => {
        // console.log('testimonials: ' + testimonials.checked)
        fetch(autosaveChecklist.ajaxUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                action    : 'autosave_checklist',
                option: 'testimonials-checkbox',
                item: testimonials.checked
            }).toString(),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));;
    });
```